# Disagreements and partial answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm trying to get a coherent “result” for the following question(s):

[How to understand "Je m'en vais."?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/how-to-understand-je-men-vais)

There was a first answer (by myself) and an other answer (by Circeus) combining a remark that did not address the original question but my answer, and another part which provided a very nice insight (according to the votes it received, and it seems it was what the OP wanted to know), but did not answer every question asked the OP.

I think the result was quite incoherent. (The answer that appears first is a disagreement with another answer and only a partial answer.)

To solve this, I thought of removing my answer and plug it into Circeus' one. But I'm not sure this would be ok with him as he disagreed with (which parts?) of what I said. I don't think just removing my answer is a solution either.
In this case I edited  Circeus' answer to make it a standalone (partial) answer, asking him to post again the disagreements and remarks as comments under my answer.

Is this an adequate solution?

How to avoid such situations?

And do somebody care, or is it just me? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you have done the right thing. Circeus can edit his answer later if he wants to address the rest of the question, or complain if he don't want his remarks to be put into comments. The choice of the accepted answer is up to the OP, so if he would rather have Circeus' partial answer, it is fine.